# how to get to object in a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have a model SiteMapModel that have a object VirtualFolderModel inside him.

```
public class SiteMapModel
{

    public SiteMapModel(DataRow data)
    {
        SMF_ID = Convert.ToInt32(data["SMF_ID"]);
        SMF_VF_ID = Convert.ToInt32(data["SMF_VF_ID"]);


        VirtualFolder = new VirtualFolderModel(data);
    }

    public VirtualFolderModel VirtualFolder;

    public int SMF_ID { get; set; }
    public int SMF_VF_ID { get; set; }


}

public class VirtualFolderModel
{
    public VirtualFolderModel(DataRow data)
    {
        VF_ID = Convert.ToInt32(data["VF_ID"]);
    }

    public int VF_ID { get; set; }
}
```

in my controller i pass the model to a view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        SiteMapData smd = new SiteMapData();
        SiteMapModel smm = new SiteMapModel(smd.GetFolderData((int)id, 15));

        return View(smm);
    }
```

how to use it in my view?

```
<div>
    <span class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Title")
    </span>
        @Html.TextBox("SMF_Name")
        @Html.ValidationMessage("SMF_Name")

    <span class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("VF_ID")
    </span>
        @Html.TextBox("VF_ID")
        @Html.ValidationMessage("VF_ID")

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

the `@Html.TextBox("VF_ID")` don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your view add this:

```
@ModelType SitemapModel
```

**Edit:** For C# please use:

```
@model SitemapModel
```

Doing that will simply tell your view what kind of model is given at runtime. In this case, it's an object of type SitemapModel.

In your view you can reference to it to `model.SMF_ID`

Comment: i get The name 'ModelType' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Are you using the final version of ASP.NET MVC 3? What kind of file is your view?

Comment: "Edit.cshtml", MVC3 razor html5

Comment: Ah I see, in C# it must be @model MyModelNamespace.MyModelType. Unfortunately VB and C# are not equal in Razor... :(